# Is "levor" a Latin word?

Tags: noun

Is "levor, levoris" officially a real word? It has no entry on Wiki or other known sources.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why it's not on Wiktionary, but [you can find it in Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dlevor), with various references to classical usage.

> lēvor (laevor), ōris, m. id.,
> I.smoothness: “haud sine principali aliquo levore,” Lucr. 2, 423: “spectantur in chartis tenuitas, densitas, candor, levor,” Plin. 13, 12, 24, § 78: “levorem corpori afferre,” id. 30, 14, 43, § 127; 37, 4, 15, § 56: “vocis,” Lucr. 4, 552.

The easiest way to find a word in Lewis and Short, in my experience, is [the Perseus morphology tool](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph). That's how I pulled up this entry.